# How to write url address with parameter

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

how to write url address with parameter like this

```
www.example.com/param1/var1/param2/var2
```

and  next  get it with :

```
$param1 =  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('param1');
$param2 =  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('param2');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default router expects that the first 3 parts in the url to be module, controller, action and then the rest of the parameters are treated as GET parameters.
You can generates such an url like this:

```
Mage::getUrl('module/controller/action', array('param1'=>'var1', 'param2'=>'var2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

check here for full deails on this :

you need to do something like this.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters

```
Mage::getUrl('cms/page/view', array('id' => 1));
// http://www.example.com/cms/page/view/id/1
```

Also your code to get these values from url is correct.